# bash history neglecting one command

Tags: bash

I have observed a very specific behaviour and I don't know what I am possibly doing to cause that.
I have an `alias` defined in `~/.bash_aliases` which goes like this:

```
alias pomo="echo 'notify-send -t 30000 \"Pomodoro!\";play ~/Downloads/bell-ring-01.wav trim 0 00:00:02 repeat 2 vol 2' | at now + 25 minutes"
```

My `history` is set in such a way as to record/show timestamps when called. I do it with the following line in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

I execute my `pomo` command N times during the day. Sometimes I get confused as to how many I've ran, so then I call the history grepping the `pomo` commands for the day. On June 23, this would look like this:

```
  history | grep pomo | grep 23/06
```

(note that I insert a space in the beginning, as I don't want this cmd to be recorded)

What puzzled me immensely was that, contrary to my recall and sometimes my paper record, I was getting **one less** `pomo` cmd recorded, in the history. Today I kept the record clean so I can show the exact command sequence, for reference:

```
(base) mike@work:~/Downloads$  date
Thu 23 Jun 2022 09:36:11 AM CEST
(base) mike@work:~/Downloads$  history | grep pomo | grep 23/06
(base) mike@work:~/Downloads$ pomo
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 127 at Thu Jun 23 10:03:00 2022
(base) mike@work:~/Downloads$  history | grep pomo | grep 23/06
  511  23/06/22 09:38:45 pomo
(base) mike@work:~/Downloads$ pomo
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 128 at Thu Jun 23 10:47:00 2022
(base) mike@work:~/Downloads$  atq
(base) mike@work:~/Downloads$   history | grep pomo | grep 23/06
  511  23/06/22 09:38:45 pomo
```

So, at the top the `date` command is not recorded (space before it) and the history of `pomo` for the day is empty. Then I run my first `pomo`. Once this is done, I fetch the history for the day, and it correctly shows me my first `pomo`.

Then, I run another one and once completed (the `atq` command shows that there's nothing pending), I fetch the history again to find that **the second pomo has not been recorded**.

Is this some kind of intended behaviour, that `history` does not record a second command identical to the preceeding one?
I am doing this "live", but what I observed in the past days is that *only one* of these commands gets neglected. The next `pomo` **will** be recorded.

Another point: I'm utterly neglecting the warning issued by `at`, about the commands executed by `/bin/sh`. Is this the root of the issue?

Comment: If you have 3 `pomo` per day, would the third be printed? I.e. is only the 2nd one skipped, or are all but the first one skipped? Respectively: What is the value of `$HISTCONTROL` in your shell?

Comment: My assumption/recollection from past days is that ONE pomo gets neglected. I am currently running one, I'll report once finished by editing this comment.
The output of `echo $HISTCONTROL` is `ignoreboth`.

Comment: Well - _ignoreboth_ is the culprit. Change it to _ingorespace_ and you are good.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the behaviour is - as suggested by [@user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428) to be traced to the value of the
`$HISTCONTROL` [variable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/histcontrol-command-in-linux-with-examples/#:%7E:text=HISTCONTROL%20variable%20is%20a%20colon,leading%20white%20space%20or%20both).

In my case it was set to `ignoreboth` so that when I ran two `pomo` consecutively, I got the second discarded.